# "Access denied" while loading the BCS list from the database

Tags: list, bcs, access-denied

I have tried to display data from SQL Server to a SharePoint page through BCS services
using SharePoint 2010 designer.

While loading I am getting this error:

```
Access denied. You do not have permission to access this content.
Correlation ID:1b1576ea-e901-471b-8af8-00457f6b62d3
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to set permissions on the BCS entity. In Central Admin go to Application Management, then Manage Service Applications.  Open the Business Data Connectivity Service and select your entity, then select Set permission from the context menu or click on the Set Object Permission button. Once you have permission to the entity the error should go away.

Here is a blog post that describes the process in detail.
http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2010/05/08/access-denied-by-business-data-connectivity-solution.aspx